# variable miles might not have been initialized

Tags: java

It keeps saying variable miles might not have been initialized? 
Here is the problem:

float km = miles * 1.609f;

Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.*;


public class MilesToKilometres
{

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception

   {

 //1 mile = 1.609 kilometre;

       int miles;
       System.out.print("17");
       float km = miles * 1.609f;
       System.out.println(miles + " miles is " + km + " kilometres. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: As Elliott Frisch indicated, you are not specifying how many miles are to be converted.

Comment: Well what value do you *expect* it to have? In this case it's not just that it *might* not be initialized - it *definitely* won't be!

Answer (score 2):

Give miles a default value. Change this

```
int miles;
```

to

```
int miles = 0;
```

or

```
int miles = 17;  //<-- Since you print "17" on the next line.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int miles;
```

is the problem as it is a local variable you need to initialize it before using it. Default values are assigned only to instance variables